# Why does iptables change the source address of incoming requests?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I am using iptables for redirecting ports for web and ssh from machine `14` to `25` as shown in the following diagram:

[image: picture]

The problem is when anyone from the internet accesses my web application, iptables changes the source IP address with its private address. Due to this I cannot know who accesses my web application.

Is there any solution to get the actual source address of traffic at machine `25` using iptables provided that my web application is also accessible to public?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.16.25  
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst 172.20.16.25 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 172.20.16.14  
iptables   -A  FORWARD  -p  tcp  --dport  80  -j  ACCEPT  
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.16.25  
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst 172.20.16.25 --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 172.20.16.14  
iptables   -A  FORWARD  -p  tcp  --dport  22  -j  ACCEPT
```

Comment: The `SNAT` rules explicitly ask iptables to change the source address. If you don't want the source to change, remove those rules (if you do, the 14 machine should be the gateway of the 25 machine)